# Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:interceptor:)'

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, alamofire

I am uploading an image on button press using `Alamofire`, but it show an ERROR at

> `AF.upload(multipartFormData: {` MultipartFormData line of method

(Note : Alamofire.upload is change to AF.upload After Alamofire 5.0 Update)

```
@IBAction func btnUploadImage(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let uploadDict = ["user_id":getUserId] as [String:String]

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

                let image :Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.uploadImg.image!, 1.0)!

                MultipartFormData.append(image, withName: "image" , fileName: "image.jpeg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                for(key,value) in uploadDict{

                    MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)}

            }, to: "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/uploadImage", encodingCompletion: {
                EncodingResult in
                switch EncodingResult{
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):

                    print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

                }        })
```

//View Controller for this code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class updateVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

//MARK:- OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var tFeditName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tFusername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tFemail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var uploadImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tVeditAddress: UITextView!


//MARK:- DECLARATIONS

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

var editName = String()
var editUserName = String()
var editEmail = String()
var editImage = UIImage()
var editAddress = String()
var getUserId = String()

//MARK:- LIFE CYCLE
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self

    tFeditName.text = editName
    tFusername.text = editUserName
    tFemail.text = editEmail
    uploadImg.image = editImage
    tVeditAddress.text = editAddress

}
//MARK:- CUSTOM FUNCTIONS

func postJSON() {

    let param = ["fullname":tFeditName.text!,"username":tFusername.text!,"email":tFemail.text!,"address":tVeditAddress.text!,"user_id":getUserId] as NSDictionary


    AF.request("http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/updatedetails", method: .post, parameters: param as? Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result{

        case .success(let json):
            print(json)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(param)
            }
        case.failure(let Error):

            print(Error)
        }
    }

}

//ImageViewPicker

func openCamera()
{
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func openGallery()
{
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have permission to access gallery.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

        uploadImg.image = pickedImage

    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



//MARK:- ACTIONS

@IBAction func btnSelectImage(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openCamera()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openGallery()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

@IBAction func btnUploadImage(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let image: UIImage? = self.uploadImg.image

    let uploadDict = ["user_id":getUserId] as [String:String]

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

        let image :Data = (image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))!

        MultipartFormData.append(image, withName: "image" , fileName: "image.jpeg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        for(key,value) in uploadDict{

            MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)}

    }, to: "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/uploadImage", encodingCompletion: {
        EncodingResult in
        switch EncodingResult{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):

            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

        }        })

}
@IBAction func btnUpdateDetails(_ sender: UIButton) {

    postJSON()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

}

Comment: I am assuming you have defined Alamofire as  AF someplace. If you see the error "UIImageJPEGRepresentation" is already replaced with self.uploadImg.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1).
Let me know if this works.

Comment: @Pavan your change for this line let image :Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.uploadImg.image!, 1.0)! is works but my error is still there , i used AF in same VC for AF.request function for updateDetrails and second is for image upload AF.upload at button press

Comment: Can you share the VC code ? Also let me know the exact version of Alamofire in your code.

Comment: i provided viewController for this code and Alamofire version is pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.3' @Pavan

Comment: i updated Alamofire version from beta 3 to beta 5 but still same error and check out my VC

Comment: I just used your code and changed AF to Alamofire and it should work. I hope you are using Xcode 10.2, let me know if you still face the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just installed pods with

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.5'
```

//  sample code

```
let image: UIImage? = self.uploadImg.image;

    let uploadDict = ["user_id":getUserId] as [String:String]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

        let image :Data = (image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))!

        MultipartFormData.append(image, withName: "image" , fileName: "image.jpeg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        for(key,value) in uploadDict{

            MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)}

    }, to: "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/uploadImage", encodingCompletion: {
        EncodingResult in
        switch EncodingResult{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):

            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

        }        })
```

Comment: Error is Solved After changing AF.request TO Alamofire.request + i Downgraded Alamofire version 5.0 to 4.8.2 that Work Successfully Thanks Brother @Pavan

Comment: Usually it should show proper error, but not sure why was it giving different error. Any its good it worked for you.

Comment: yes the code was right but error is from alamofire version its giving different error, again thanks for your help:) @Pavan

Answer (score 1):

From Alamofire 5.0 Migration Guide:

> - MulitpartFormData’s API has changed and the top level upload methods to create and upload MultipartFormData have been updated to match other request APIs, so it’s not longer necessary to deal with the Result of the multipart encoding.

So your code should be like this:

```
@IBAction func btnUploadImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let uploadDict = ["user_id": "getUserId"] as [String:String]

  AF.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

    let image: Data = self.uploadImg.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!

     MultipartFormData.append(image, withName: "image" , fileName: "image.jpeg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            for(key,value) in uploadDict {
                MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to: "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/uploadImage", method: .post, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json", 
         "authorization": "bearer \(token)"])
   .responseJSON { (response) in
            debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
   }
}
```

So you will not need `encodingCompletion` closure and use responseJSON immediately.

Comment: How can you add a header at this method? Because it's given me this error : Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:interceptor:fileManager:)'

Comment: @ShardaPrasad after url add method and headers, I updated the answer please check – Hosny 22 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

check for this:
 https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2942
Search for "Create a parameter-dictionary [String: Data] and then append the entries before the actual file"

Comment: this is better as a comment, not an answer