# Post with HTTP a struct Codable as a JSON array with Alamofire

Tags: swift, http, alamofire, codable

I am using **Swift 4.2**, **Xcode 10.2.1** and **Alamofire 4.8.2**

Note: *I used to use Alamofire 5 but there is no documentation yet*

I have this codable:

```swift
struct User: Codable {


    var name : String
    var lastname : String
    var email : String
    var passwd : String
    var grade: String
    var img: String
}
```

Then I assign each variable a nameField value.

```swift
       let user = User(name: nameField.text!, lastname: lastnameField.text!, email: emailField.text!, passwd: passwdField.text!, grade: gradeField.text!, img: base64ImageString)
```

I submit this to my function,
  `submitRegistration(for: user)`

And then in my function with **Alamofire**

```
func submitRegistration(for user: User) {

    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, User: user, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
}
```

But then I get the following error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'request(_:method:parameters:encoding:headers:)'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685241/using-alamofire-and-codable-for-put-request

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me

[Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:interceptor:)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686247/ambiguous-reference-to-member-upload-tomethodheadersinterceptor)

Or Try This Method

```
func postJSON() {

    let url = "Your URL"

    let parameters = ["name":tFname.text!,"Lastname":tFLastname.text!,"password":tFpassword.text!,"email":tFemail.text!,"address":tVaddress.text!] as NSDictionary

    AF.request("http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/register", method: .post, parameters: (parameters as! Parameters), encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem is that my let = user is in one file and the function is in another